# java.lang.Object o = 1;//why does this compile?

Tags: java, autoboxing

I was doing one of these online Java tests and I was asked this question:

Q: Indicate correct assignment:

```
Long l = 1; 
Double d = 1;
Integer i = 1;
String s = 1;
Object o = "1";
System.out.println(o);
o = 1;
System.out.println(o);
```

Please try it yourself before you go any further.

Well I can tell you I got it  wrong, I investigated it and found:

```
//Long l = 1; //cannot widen and then box
Long ll = 1L;//no need to widen, just box
//Double d = 1;//cannot widen and then box
Double dd = 1d;//no need to widen, just box
Integer i = 1;//no need to widen, just box
//String s = 1;//cannot do implicit casting here

Object o = "1";//this compiles and is just plain weird 
System.out.println(o);//output is 1
o = 1;//this also compiles and is also weird 
System.out.println(o);//output is 1
```

Can someone tell why:

`Object o = 1;` and `Object o = "1";`

compile and output 1 in both cases, this is puzzling me.

Many thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`"1"` is an instance of String class, and String is a subclass of Object class in Java (as any other class). `1` is boxed into an Integer, which is also derived from Object.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer, but I have to tell you I feel so stupid now I should know this.

Comment: @Ramo: to not question something you don't know would be stupid :-)

Answer (score 3):

Because `"1"` is an instance of a `String`, and since 1.5 `1` is auto-boxable to an `Integer`; both types are subtypes of `Object`. Before autoboxing was introduced, `Object o = 1;` would not compile.

To get the most out of this learning experience, you should be aware of `Object`'s `getClass()` method. By adding `System.out.println(o.getClass().getName())`, you can also print the name of the class that the object referred to by `o` belongs to. In your case, they are `java.lang.String` (for `(Object) "1"`) and `java.lang.Integer` (for `(Object) 1`).

Just for completion, I should mention that you can now also do `Object o = false;`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first case "1" is a `String` literal, so a subclass of object, hence assignable to it. As a string, it output of 1 is relatively simple.

In the second case, auto-boxing is occurring. `Integer` is a subclass of object, hence assignable to it. Similarly, the output of 1 then makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `o` is of type `Object`. Every object, in java, extends the class `Object`. So... when you say `Object o = 1`, it converts 1 to from `int` to `Integer`, which is an `Object`. Similarly, "1" is a `String` which is an `Object`. In both cases, calling `System.out.println` on an `Object` invokes the `Object`s `toString` method. In both cases, it will print 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `Object o = anything;` where `anything` is any object because all classes derive from the `Object` class. It works with primitives because of autoboxing feature which came in java 1.5.